# React JS - Route - Element type is invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm new to React JS and am trying to implement something similar to the Angular sample application.

I have a table of customers and want to seen the selected customer at the bottom of the table.

I tried the following with react-router-dom:

```
// index.js 
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

ReactDOM.render((<BrowserRouter><App /></BrowserRouter>), document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();


// App.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom/Route';

import Customers from './components/customers';
import Customer from './components/customer';

export default class App extends Component {
    state = {
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Customers />
                <Route path={`/customer/:id`} component={Customer} />
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}


// customers.jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class Customers extends Component {
    state = {
        customers: []
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <header className="jumbotron"><h1>Customer List</h1></header>

                <div className="container">
                    <table className="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Address</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {this.state.customers.map(c => (<tr key={c.id}><td><Link to={`/customer/${c.id}`}>{c.name}</Link></td><td>{c.address}</td></tr>))}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <hr />
                </div>

                <footer className="footer">&copy; 2018</footer>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const result = await fetch('http://api.com/customers');
        const customers = await result.json();
        this.setState({ customers });
        console.log(this.state.customers);
    }
}


// customer.jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Customer extends Component {
    render() {
        return (<p>Customer</p>);
    };
}
```

The line in App.js that adds the Route (Route path={`/customer/:id`} component={Customer}) is causing the error.  If I remove that line I can see the table of customers but as soon as I add this line, then I get that error message.

Did I miss something on how this router works?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Event changing App.js to this very simple version causes the error

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom/Route';

export default class App extends Component {
    state = {
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Route exact path='/' render={() => (<h1>Hello</h1>)} />
                <Route exact path='/customer' render={() => (<h1>Customer</h1>)} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The full error message is:

**Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.**

Comment: have you tried replacing `<React.Fragment>` with a `<div>`?

Comment: maybe there's something wrong with `Customer` component.

Comment: your code works without errors -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-szzsq7

Comment: @marzelin, thanks for your input.  I have tried every which way and it does not work on my browser.  Any suggestions on a configuration I should check?

Comment: looking at the error it's rather build process issue rather than a browser

Comment: I don't see any compile errors or build errors on the console.  It says Compiled successfully!  It's there a step in the javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this:

```
import {Route} from "react-router-dom/Route";
```

to this:

```
import Route from "react-router-dom/Route";
```

Route is a default export when you access it directly: `"react-router-dom/Route"`
You can use named exports when you import `Route` from base package

```
import {Route} from "react-router-dom";
```

But don't mix the two.

Comment: Thanks you very much for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

I feel the issue is with back ticks in path. Can you try with this

```
    render() {
          return (
              <React.Fragment>
                   <Customers />
                   <Route path='/customer/:id' component={Customer} />
             </React.Fragment>
           );
      }
```

OR

```
    render() {
          return (
              <React.Fragment>
                   <Customers />
                   <Route path={'/customer/:id'} component={Customer} />
             </React.Fragment>
           );
      }
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried it with single and double quotes, with and without the braces, still the same error.  Please note that if I remove the Route tag, the page displays fine.

Comment: Looks like the issue is with Customer component either it is not imported properly nor exported

Comment: Are you using react-router-Redux?

Comment: I'm not using react-router-Redux.  Also, I just updated with a very simple route and still get the error.  Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you have a syntax error in the `Customer` component's `render()` method which will be causing issue when you attempt to use/render this.

Try the following fix:

```
export default class Customer extends Component {
    render() {
        return (<p> Customer</p>); // <-- remove the whitespace in 
                                   //     closing tag </p> like so
    };
}
```

Comment: Still the same error after removing the white space. Thanks for the input.  Please note that if I remove the Route tag, the page displays fine.

Comment: what version of react, react-dom, and react-router-dom are you using?

Comment: react: ^16.5.0, react-dom: ^16.5.0, react-router-dom: ^4.3.1